# Get dynamic elements from JavaFX container

Tags: java, javafx

i created a simple GUI, using JavaFX with fxml. One part of the program is using fxml and other generate dynamic GUI. So, i created `javafx.scene.controller.Accordion` with fxml and add panes inside it with code:

```
@FXML
Accordion accordionPlant;


public void init(){

    accordionPlant.getPanes().add(createTitledPanePlant(1));
    accordionPlant.getPanes().add(createTitledPanePlant(2));
}

protected TitledPane createTitledPanePlant(int index){

    TilePane tile = new TilePane(Orientation.HORIZONTAL, 5, 5);
    Label typeLabel = new Label("Тип выпуска");
    TextField typeText = new TextField();
    VBox typeContainer = new VBox(typeLabel,typeText);

    Label bankLabel = new Label("Берег");
    Tooltip.install(bankLabel, new Tooltip("Берег, с которого производится выпуск"));
    TextField bankText = new TextField();
    VBox bankContainer = new VBox(bankLabel,bankText);

    tile.getChildren().addAll(typeContainer, bankContainer);

    TitledPane titledPane = new TitledPane("Параметры выпуска " + index, tile);

    return titledPane;
}
```

After that user click on the button and the program should find all `TextField` and calculate their value. So how it must be done correctly or comfortable?

I tried to get all panes of accordion:

```
void test(){
    for (TitledPane pane: accordionPlant.getPanes()) {
        pane.getChildrenUnmodifiable().get(0); //blah, blah
    }
}
```

but i think it isn't a good idea, especially using index. I need only textfields. Is there any way of `implements of` ?

Comment: Why don't you just keep the text fields in instance variables in the controller?

Comment: @James_D There are about 10-15 panes. Is it okey to create ArrayList of TextFields? Moreover i need to calculate the sum of textField only inside one Pane. So it means i try to get 10-15 sums

Comment: "Is it ok to create `ArrayList` of `TextField`s": sure, why not? Or a map, if that's more convenient. It's not really clear what the question is. Are you sure it's not better to define each of the panes in its own FXML and with its own controller anyway?

Comment: @James_D i feel, that there is a simple solution, without creating arrays or instances. I will wait some time, if nobody helps, i will use your solution ^_^

Comment: If you are looking for a hack, you can use a [CSS lookup](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#lookupAll-java.lang.String-). But I don't understand why you wouldn't just structure this correctly; define either a class or a FXML+controller for the panes, factor the common functionality into a superclass, etc. JavaFX is just normal Java, you should code it the same way.

Comment: If you have dynamic elements, why not just store them in a `List` when you create them? That way you don't have to try to get them from a container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have dynamic elements, why not just store them in a `List` when you create them? That way you don't have to try to get them from a container. You are probably only interested in the `Controller`, but I posted the whole app. If you look in `createTitledPanePlant` you can see where I add the `TextFields` to the `List` -> `List<TextField> textFieldContainer = new ArrayList();`

> Main

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXApplication115 extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

> Controller

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.scene.control.Accordion;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane;
import javafx.scene.control.Tooltip;
import javafx.scene.layout.TilePane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable
{

    @FXML
    private Label label;
    @FXML
    private Accordion accordionMain;

    List<TextField> textFieldContainer = new ArrayList();

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event)
    {
        //Sum TextField
        double total = 0;

        for (TextField node : textFieldContainer) {
            double value;
            try {
                value = Double.parseDouble(node.getText());
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                value = 0;
            }

            total += value;

        }
        label.setText("Sum: " + total);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb)
    {
        // TODO
        accordionMain.getPanes().add(createTitledPanePlant(1));
        accordionMain.getPanes().add(createTitledPanePlant(2));

    }

    protected TitledPane createTitledPanePlant(int index)
    {
        TilePane tile = new TilePane(Orientation.HORIZONTAL, 5, 5);
        Label typeLabel = new Label("Тип выпуска");
        TextField typeText = new TextField();
        textFieldContainer.add(typeText);//Add your textField to the container when you create it
        VBox typeContainer = new VBox(typeLabel, typeText);

        Label bankLabel = new Label("Берег");
        Tooltip.install(bankLabel, new Tooltip("Берег, с которого производится выпуск"));
        TextField bankText = new TextField();
        textFieldContainer.add(bankText);//Add your textField to the container when you create it
        VBox bankContainer = new VBox(bankLabel, bankText);

        tile.getChildren().addAll(typeContainer, bankContainer);

        TitledPane titledPane = new TitledPane("Параметры выпуска " + index, tile);

        return titledPane;
    }
}
```

> FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Accordion?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="486.0" prefWidth="431.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" fx:controller="javafxapplication115.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
        <Button fx:id="button" layoutX="179.0" layoutY="437.0" onAction="#handleButtonAction" text="Sum nodes" />
        <Label fx:id="label" layoutX="163.0" layoutY="37.0" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="106.0" />
      <Accordion fx:id="accordionMain" layoutX="115.0" layoutY="72.0" prefHeight="310.0" prefWidth="202.0" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: If i understand right, creating List of elements is the best way to solve my problem. so, okey. Thanks, guys